# Can a Virtual Machine be part of multiple virtual networks at the same time in Windows Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-network

We are building a saas application over Azure. We want to provide 'Virtual Network feature (optional)' to client. If client subscribe for 'Virtual Network', we are planning to wrap VM's into virtual network and allow him to connect to his local network.

But in case two clients choose this feature, we will have to create separate VNet over same VM (since our application is running on same VMs).

Is this feasible or we are working on wrong direction?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The architecture you are suggesting will not work in Azure (nor in AWS either).  You would first require multiple NICs in VMs which are not currently supported in Azure.